# python django запасной адрес для базы

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Можно ли как-то сделать резервный путь для запасной базы. Базы идентичны. Просто если не сможет по одному адресу достучаться до базы чтобы по второму попробовал подключиться

Comment: А почему по первому не сможет? Какой-то странный кейс.

Comment: Да допустим, что отключили свет.